# How to render dynamic elements in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create an app where users can select what kind of `vuetify` element they would like to render on the page? So I have 4 options that users can select from. I want to render the respective `vuetify` component on click, so if the user selects `divider` a `<v-divider> </v-divider>` should render, for a `spacer`, a `<v-spacer></v-spacer>` and for a `toolbar` a `<v-toolbar></v-toolbar>` and if they select `text` then a `<v-btn></v-btn>` with text would be displayed. I am really stuck on how I can do it.

This is a sample [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/wvKrYdR?editors=1111)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      elements: [{
          title: "Divider",
          value: "divider"
        },
        {
          title: "Spacer",
          value: "spacer"
        },
        {
          title: "Toolbar",
          value: "toolbar"
        },
        {
          title: "Text",
          value: "text"
        }
      ],
      selected: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    renderElements() {
      console.log(this.selected);
      this.selected = [];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout column>
        <v-flex v-for="el in elements" :key="el.value">
          <v-checkbox :value="el.value" v-model="selected" :label="el.title"></v-checkbox>
        </v-flex>
        <v-btn @click="renderElements"> Render Dynamic Elements</v-btn>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      elements: [
        {
          title: "Divider",
          value: "v-divider",
          show: false
        },
        {
          title: "Spacer",
          value: "v-spacer",
          show: false
        },
        {
          title: "Toolbar",
          value: "v-toolbar",
          show: false
        },
        {
          title: "Text",
          value: "v-btn",
          show: false
        }
      ],
      selected: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    renderElements() {
      console.log(this.selected);
      for(let i=0; i<this.elements.length; i++)
      {
        this.elements[i].show = this.selected.includes(i);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout column>
        <v-checkbox v-for="(item, i) in elements"
            :key="i"
            :label="item.title"
            :value="i"
            v-model="selected"
         ></v-checkbox>
        
        <v-btn @click="renderElements"> Render Dynamic Elements</v-btn>
        <component v-for="(item, i) in elements" :key="i + 10" :is="item.value" v-if="item.show">{{ item.title }}</component>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to use [dynamic components](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html):

```
<component v-for="(el, i) in selected" :key="i" :is="el.value"></component>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      elements: [
        {
          title: "Divider",
          value: "v-divider"
        },
        {
          title: "Spacer",
          value: "v-spacer"
        },
        {
          title: "Toolbar",
          value: "v-toolbar"
        },
        {
          title: "Text",
          value: "v-btn"
        }
      ],
      selected: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    renderElements() {
      console.log(this.selected);
      this.selected = [];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout column>

        <v-flex v-for="el in elements" :key="el.value">
          <v-checkbox :value="el" v-model="selected" :label="el.title">
          </v-checkbox>
        </v-flex>
        <v-btn @click="renderElements"> Render Dynamic Elements</v-btn>
                
        <component v-for="(el, i) in selected" :key="i" :is="el.value"></component>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: The pen doesn't seem to be displaying any elements though? :(

Comment: I update the code inline to check, i am not using the button to render the elements. its based on selected array